# Redirect input from file

Tags: bash, input, redirect

I'm writing a script (TEST.sh) that must run another script (TASK.sh)... 
Task.sh need two input... so I was thinking to redirect input from a file (I need to automize everything)...

So, I was using theese solutions:

```
exec "$assessment_tests/task.sh" "$parameters" < "$testdir/stdin" > "$testdir/output2";
```

But I receive an "access denied" error

And this other solution

```
bash "$assessment_tests/task.sh" "$parameters" < "$testdir/stdin" > "$testdir/output2";
```

(I've changed exec with bash)

In the second way i can run the script task.sh but in output2 i always find the message "Input wrong" where "Input wrong" is the output of task.sh... But I should obtain "Input ok"...

My stdin file is just a row with the value "my_input"

Any suggestion?

thanx

Comment: Yes. Post the script in http://paste.ubuntu.com and add a link here. Without knowing what it does, how can we know what's going wrong?

Comment: Honestly it was a bit complex... Here the code of task.sh

http://paste.ubuntu.com/8177422/

and here the input

CD1243423kk,0dc3dopwlz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string `CD1243423kk,0dc3dopwlz` doesn't pass the `if` statement:

```
if [[ ! $input =~ ^[a-k][a-kC-Z0-9]{4,},[a-z0-9]{3,}$ ]]; then
    echo "Errore Autenticazione";
    exit 21;
fi
```

Fix that and you fix your problem.

Remember that it's case sensitive. The first group needs to be `[a-kA-K]` and then your string will pass.

Comment: :O Thanx... Oh my God I had tested the single file but in the end i took a wrong input :( im sorry